# How to pass TransactionContext in callable using EJB and JPA

Tags: ejb, eclipselink

I am having project in EJB 3.0 and i'm using callable and ManagedExecutor for multiThreading, but the method i'm calling in callable is giving TransactionRequiredException each time any refresh,merge or persist method got called. Is there any way I can send transaction context, so that it can run smoothly. I'm using eclipseLink JPA and glassfish 4.1.

Comment: If you are using JTA, which is container controlled so you will have to setup your container.  There are numerous examples of using resource local though, which allows you to control the transaction through JPA on a non-JTA datasource.

Comment: I'm using JTA only but i'm not aware of the setup i need to do with container. I tried @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) also but still the problem persists. Even though I want callable processing within same transaction but just for the sake of trying i tried this one.